# Splitting a DTMF signal from a wav file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, octave, dtmf

Here is the context of the problem: I have a DTMF signal in wav format, I have to identify the number sequence it has encoded. I must do so using fast fourier transform in Matlab, implying that I read the wav file using `wavread` and to identify each number that is seperated by 40ms silence or more.

Here is my code so far:

```
[signal, fs] = wavread( 'C:\Temp\file.wav' );  % here, fs = 8000Hz

N = 512;                    
T = 1/fs;                   
L = length( signal )        
samples = fs / 1000 * 40    
windows = floor(L / samples) 
t = (1:L)/fs;

figure(1), plot(t, signal);
```

Here is what the `figure 1` looks like, that is the signal read from the wav:
[image]

How can I effectively split the signal into pieces so that I can then do an FFT on each of the 10 pieces seperately to decode the corresponding numbers?

Comment: Using an FFT for this task is not really appropriate - typically DTMF detection is performed in the time domain using a filter bank, either using conventional filters or the Goertzel algorithm.

Comment: Appropriate? An fft will do the job just fine, even though it might not be the most efficient solution.

Comment: Considering I am doing this for an academic purpose, it is mandatory to use the FFT.

Comment: @JFBeaulieu Hey do you mind if I have a look at your final code? I do have the exact same problem as yours and I was wondering if you would like to share your final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
windowSize = 256;   
nbWindows = floor(L / windowSize);

for i=1:nbWindows
    coeffs = fft(signal((i-1)*windowSize+1:i*windowSize));    
    plot(abs(coeffs(1:N)));
    waitforbuttonpress
end;
```

This way it is possible to shift the window until the end of the input signal

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

- Find the envelope of the signal in the time domain (see Hilbert transform).
- Smooth the envelope a bit.
- Take the diff and find peaks to get the onsets of the tones.
- Use the onsets to pick frames and find the spectrum using fft.
- Find the index of the max in each of the spectrums and convert them to a frequency.

The tricky part in this is to get a robust onset detector in point 3. The peaks in the difference you pick, has to be of a certain size in order to qualify as on onset. If your tones are of varying strength this might pose a problem, but from your image of the time signal it doesn't seem like a problem.

Regards